# divisible subgroup without axiom of choice

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, axiom-of-choice

the theorem asserting that *the divisible subgroup of an Abelian group is a direct summand* depends on Zorn's lemma.

in ZF without AC is there a construction which yields a model of an Abelian group which does *not* have this property?

*note:my motive in asking this is less curiosity about group theory and more the hope that answers might help me begin to understand the still-elusive ideas of forcing and boolean-valued models. apologies if the question is unfit for purpose*

Comment: When you say "this property", what exactly do you mean? That it doesn't have a maximal divisible subgroup which is a direct summand?

Comment: Asaf, i was naively assuming that the abelian group would have a unique divisible subgroup. could you clarify this for me ?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Q^2$ is divisible, but $\Bbb Q$ as a subgroup is also divisible. The use of Zorn is, I suppose, in obtaining a maximal divisible subgroup, and then showing that it is a direct summand.

Comment: (I also think that if you are trying to understand forcing and Boolean-valued models, then axiom of choice related constructions might be too advanced for you at the moment.)

Comment: well i'll accept your advice on that point! the use of Zorn (in the proof i've seen (Marshal Hall, 1959) is to obtain  a maximal subgroup which trivially intersects the divisible subgroup. divisibility allows one to show, by a simple descent technique on the positive integers, that this maximal subgroup, together with the divisible subgroup, generate the whole group)